# Change form field width

Tags: sharepoint-online, column, custom-form

I am using SPO. I have a custom New Item form with a 255 character single line of text field called [Description]

I would like to increase the width of the field input box in the custom New Item form. I belive it is currently at 400px and I would like 2000px

I have tried to adjust the width in SPD by editing the form but it had no impact.

Does anyone have any suggestions, perhaps javascript that works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS-only. (Inside a script editor webpart on the form aspx page).

The only thing you need to change is the TR child element (`tr:nth-child(1)`). Now it targets the first column in the form. The first TD is always the label field and the second is the actual textbox.

```
   <style type="text/css">
    tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(2) > span > .ms-long {
    width:2000px;
    }
    </style>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the code above. I pasted it into a Script Editor webpart added to the page but it hasnt had any impact. Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: Did you add it to the actual list form? new.aspx? And do you have the new list experience?

Comment: Hi Christoffer, i mustve done something wrong the first time. Repeated the process and now it works. Thank you.

Comment: No problem. :) I was thinking that if the modern list experience were enabled, you would have needed different code.

Comment: That is a very very specific path you are declaring with all those **>** (direct child elements). INPUTs having a class ``ms-long`` can be targeted with ``input.ms-long`` (note there is no space in between) A Form also has textareas, if you want to include those just do ``.ms-long``

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman That was the first thing that came to my mind without any coffee in my body. :)

Comment: That's why I don't read SO till after my first coffee (its 11:20 here now in Amsterdam)

Comment: As in Sweden. :)

Answer (score 0):

Add a content editor webpart to the custom list form and add the below code inside it

```
$("input[title='Description']").attr("style","width:2000px;");
```

If your `Description` field is Required field then just use below code

```
 $("input[title='Description Required Field']").attr("style","width:2000px;");
```

Dont forget to add Jquery reference above this code

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I used the following code but it hasn impacted the field width: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$("input[title='Description']").attr("style","width:2000px;");
</script>

Comment: Can you just do inspect element of your browser (press F12) and see what is the title of your text field?